# How to break at a specific function or line with the Node.js node inspect command line step debugger without modifying the source?

Tags: node.js

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

function myfunc(i) {
  return i + 1;
}

let i = 1;
i += 1;
console.log(myfunc(i));
```

Start debugging:

```
node inspect main.js
```

Leaves me at:

```
Break on start in main.js:7
  5 }
  6 
> 7 let i = 1;
  8 i += 1;
  9 console.log(myfunc(i));
```

Now I want to go directly to `myfunc` without:

- `n`, `n`, `s`
- adding a `debugger` statement into `myfunc`
- using the browser GUI-based debugger

I tried something like:

```
sb myfunc
```

to add a breakpoint on `myfunc`, but `sb` only seems to be able to set breakpoints at the current line:

```
sb myfunc
   ^^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Tested on node v12.18.1.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_breakpoints), it looks to me like the right syntax is:

```
sb('myfunc()')
```

to set a breakpoint on the first line of a function named `myfunc`.

You could also set a breakpoint on a specific line number with:

```
sb(5)
```